# Dynamic z-index for repeating duplicate Components

Tags: html, css, reactjs

At the moment my application is very dynamic. We get a list of components and insert it into the DOM one by one, it's not a repeat. The components aren't always in the same order.

I have an odd edge case where if 4 document widgets are inserted

[image]

And if they are toggled, the add icon remains at the top

[image]

This is the style 'X' icon has

```
element.style {
    position: absolute;
    margin: -10px;
    z-index: 200;
    width: auto;
    inset: 0px 0px auto auto;
}
```

I am able to manually fix by decrementing z-index of each 'X' icon after. EX. 200, 199, 198, 197
[image]

May I ask how do I properly implement the z-index so that the component z-index decrement each time it appears in the DOM

Small Example here
http://jsfiddle.net/f8jn04tb/1/

Comment: are you using `Array.prototype.map()` to render these?

Comment: What order do you want to archive exactly? Do you only want to have the panels above the 'X'-icon or do you want toalso have some particular order among the panels?

Comment: @Reizo I need it decrementing. First one to have 200, second one to have 199.

Comment: You do not necessarily need to set the z-index to archive what you want. Thus I am asking for your actual goal (see [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).

Comment: @Reizo order does not matter. I've stated in the post the components aren't always in the same order. What I want to achieve is the elements to decrease in z index for each time it repeats. If you have suggestions for a better solution, I'm listening.

Comment: Okay, so one kind of hack would be to have the lowest element first in the HTML-doc and use `{ display: flex; flex-direction: reverse-column; }` on the container. Then the first panel will automatically be rendered on top.

Comment: If that's not an option thought, I think you need to provide some more information on your HTML and other css classes, like the one of the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of what I think is what you're wanting to achieve. Count the icons you have, set a variable of a starting amount to countdown from, loop through the icons containers to set the z-index counting down from your countdown variable.

```js
let $iconCount = $('.container > ul > li').length,
    $startingAmount = 200;
for(let i = $iconCount; i > 0; i--) {
    $('.container > ul > li:nth-child('+i+')').css('z-index',($startingAmount+1)-i);
}
```

```css
.container > ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.container > ul > li .popup {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    left: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    top: 0;
}
.container > ul > li .close {
    display: block;
    background-color: #1f81bd;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    text-align: center;

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin: -10px;
    z-index: 200;
    top: 0;
}
.container > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
    z-index: 1;
}
.container > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 2;
}
.container > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
    z-index: 3;
}
.container > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="icon">Icon 1</span>
                <span class="close">X</span>        
                <div class="popup">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Sub item 11</li>
                        <li>Sub item 12</li>
                        <li>Sub item 13</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="title">Icon 2</span>
                <span class="close">X</span>        
                <div class="popup">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Sub item 21</li>
                        <li>Sub item 22</li>
                        <li>Sub item 23</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="icon">Icon 3</span>
                <span class="close">X</span>
                <div class="popup">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Sub item 31</li>
                        <li>Sub item 32</li>
                        <li>Sub item 33</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="icon">Icon 4</span>
                <span class="close">X</span>                
                <div class="popup">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Sub item 41</li>
                        <li>Sub item 42</li>
                        <li>Sub item 43</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```